# Access Query or VBA - Split data into line level

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How do I get the following

Project  | Code 1 | Code 2  | Code 3

1 | a | b | c

2 | a | d

translate into getting code on line level by project?

Project  | Code

1 | a

1 | b

1 | c

2 | a

2 | d

I am currently doing this manually but the problem is I have 30 codes. My current process is do a select query and then do a union for all 30 codes. Can someone help me out with this? I know a vba script will do the job but weren't sure how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: is there a particular reason you put the codes as columns in the same table instead of in their own table (which would have the structure you're looking for)?

Comment: Yes. The code could be everywhere from code 1-30. So it's hard for me to match it against another table. So I want to be able to look up a code within code 1- 30 and match it against another table that has code 1-30

Comment: @serakfalcon any idea how to do this?

Comment: what will you do with the result set after you have it? a Crosstab (pivot) query would generate the layout you're after, but this output would be difficult to use in a form or report (for instance)

Comment: @Futochan I've just edited my answer. There was a little error in it, now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

With this function you can read data from a table with N codes fields named (code1, code2, ..., codeN) and write them to a table with only two fields:

```
Function Verticalize(numberofcodes As Integer)
        Dim sql As String
        Dim rst As New ADBDb.Recordset
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tname"
        rst.Open sql, CurrentProject.AccessConnection
        While Not rst.EOF
            For i = 1 To numberofcodes
                DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into tdest values (" & rst(0) & "," & rst("code") & Str(i) & ")"
            Next i
            rst.MoveNext
        Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can support any number of project codes by creating a new table, let's call it `ProjectCode`.

So you'd have one table for `Projects`, that doesn't have anything to do with codes.
If codes have extra data attached, you can create a `Code` table and add that information.

`ProjectCode` helps the database to see how they are related by using a JOIN. the structure would be

```
ProjectID | CodeID
```

What I've done for cases like this, is to use the main form for projects, and have a continuous form in datasheet view as a subform, linking to the `ProjectCode`-like table, and link the ID from Projects to the ProjectID of the subform. (`Link Master Fields` & `Link Child Fields` properties of the subform object), note you'll want to hide ProjectID on the subform.

To get a list of codes, you can just query `ProjectCode` with the project ID. if you need additional information from projects, use a join:

```
SELECT * FROM Projects INNER JOIN ProjectCode ON ProjectCode . ProjectID = Projects.ID
WHERE ID = 'some id'
```

Note that the information from Projects will be repeated for each code.